# Vlookup Error When Using Concat Reference Fields

Tags: excel

I am trying to use some a vlookup to pull in data with dynamic unique IDs. The unique IDs are all concatenated fields. The values look identical but I can't get a value to come thru just #N/A. When I put text in as the first reference field it works just fine.

The purpose is so when you update the start of the week it will update all the unique IDs for the fields and be able to pull in the data you need. I thought this would be easier than trying to do an index and match.

Here is a link to some of the sample data I have been using to try and get this to work.

[VLookUp Error Sheet](https://ruralkingsupply-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/amcclay_ruralking_com/EWIHBNsfJ5lGjO1OUu8wXk0BCp9o6xch1Ny8lnrL0dFU6g?e=slO0BB)

Thank you

Comment: There are white spaces in the sheet named `Sheet1` in column `C` also your formula `VLOOKUP()` is not using relative `absolute reference` for `lookup_value` please check. But you should not post links as well.

Comment: Also for example `lookup_value`  --> `450781st A DockLoader` has spaces while in `Sheet 1` the lookup value had no spaces after and between `1st` & `A`. I think these are typos, you need to check first clearly. However it has been fixed. please check and confirm

Comment: if the data always has the searched or indexed column on the left then vlookup works well, but if other columns become the ones to use as an index then index() with match() gives that flexibility without changing the data.

Comment: To trap and get rid of leading or trailing spaces use trim() and a helper column then paste values...